# Pandas: Dataframe has just one entry

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, api

I am currently working on comparing Corona data of Germany from different sources. For this I used the RKI API and get the following as Pandas Dataframe:

0          ObjectId                    [{'name': 'IdBundesland', 'type': 'esriFieldTy...                   True  [{'attributes': {'IdBundesland': 5, 'Bundeslan...           ObjectId                              True

But this output is wrong, because it just has one entry and the entry does'nt look like it should. Does anyone have an idea what could be the reason? Maybe `pd.json_normalize(r_json)` but without this I get a ValueError.

My Code (Link to API in Code):

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import json

link = 'https://services7.arcgis.com/mOBPykOjAyBO2ZKk/arcgis/rest/services/RKI_COVID19/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=json'
payload = {}
response = requests.request(
    method='get',
    url=link,
    params=payload,
    timeout=5
)

r_json = response.json()
r_json = pd.json_normalize(r_json)
# print(response.status_code)
# print(r_json)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(r_json)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have overly complexified your requests query:

Having check the bellow website seems like you can use "resultOffset" in your url in order to loop through the whole dataset.

[enter link description here](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/query-related-records-feature-service-.htm)

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

exceeded_transfer_limit: bool = True
offset: int = 0
result_df = pd.DataFrame()

while exceeded_transfer_limit:

    base_url = f"https://services7.arcgis.com/mOBPykOjAyBO2ZKk/arcgis/rest/services/RKI_COVID19/" \
               f"FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&outSR=4326&resultOffset={offset}&f=json"
    web_response = requests.get(url=base_url)
    web_json = web_response.json()
    print(web_json)
    
    # print(type(web_json))
    print(web_json.keys())
    if 'exceededTransferLimit' in web_json.keys():
        exceeded_transfer_limit = web_json['exceededTransferLimit'] #seems like this never return False, key just get ommited if not exceeded
    else:
        exceeded_transfer_limit=False
    print(f"exceededTransferLimit: {exceeded_transfer_limit}")

    result_df = result_df.append(pd.DataFrame([dict_row['attributes'] for dict_row in web_json['features']]))

    offset += 5000

    if len(result_df) >= 500000:
        result_df.to_csv(f"covid_data_{offset}.csv", sep=',', index=False)
        result_df = pd.DataFrame()

if len(result_df) > 0:
    result_df.to_csv(f"covid_data_{offset}_final.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to increment the offset by the number of the rows actually read, otherwise you get multiple or missing data sets:

```
...
print(f"exceededTransferLimit: {exceeded_transfer_limit}")

newData_df = pd.DataFrame([dict_row['attributes'] for dict_row in web_json['features']])
result_df = result_df.append(newData_df)

offset += len(newData_df) # get next set of rows

if len(result_df) ...
```